# How to make alias of list, python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I recently started working on my discord bot in python, and I made a "guess the character based on picture" game. I created a list of pictures of characters, but I want to make:

link on picture = character name

But I am totally lost, I didnt find any help on google.

```
Links = ["https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/7/299404.jpg", "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/12/299406.jpg"]
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I think you need to link character with the url,  you can store character name with links in dictionary ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with just lists:

```
Links = ["https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/7/299404.jpg", 
        "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/12/299406.jpg"]

Chars = ["Izuku Midoriya", "Katsuki Bakugo"]
```

Guess the character?
Now if you show `Links[0]` the corresponding character will be `Chars[0]`

---

Although, a much better way and more appropriate way would be to use dictionaries.

```
mydict = {"Izuku Midoriya" : "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/7/299404.jpg", 
          "Katsuki Bakugo" : "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/12/299406.jpg" }


for character, link in mydict.items(): 
     # show the picture from the link
     # <put your code on how you want to show your link> 
     
     # receive the guess from user
     guess = input('Enter your guess: ')
     if guess.lower() == character.lower():
         print('You guessed the right character!')
```